# Replace a=b to b=a with regex

Tags: regex

I have a long list (about 40 lines) like:

```
tbxName.Text = clientName
tbxCity.Text = clientCity
tbxStreet.Text = clientStreet
...
etc
```

I'd like to get it the opposite way without writing or copy/pasting it all by hand

```
clientName = tbxName.Text
clientCity = tbxCity.Text
clientStreet = tbxStreet.Text
....
```

Preferably I'd like to ignore spaces between names and = sign so my entry could be clientName = tbxName.Text, clientName=tbxName.Text, clientName= tbxName.Text, clientName    =    tbxName.Text and so on

Is it possible with Regex formula?

Comment: Where is this data found?In a db?If its a one time deal just do it manually.

Comment: From the [tag:regex] tag wiki: "Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using." The reason behind this is, that there are different syntaxes for regular expressions.

Comment: Yes it is possible with a regex. Maybe you can do a little bit of research about regexes and try something out before you ask a question. If you still can't succeed then show what you've tried in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
s/(.*)=(.*)/\2=\1/
^ ^^^ ^     ^  ^
| ||| |     |  | First captured group
| ||| |     | Second captured group
| ||| | Literal = sign
| ||| Repeat 0 or more times
| || Match any character
| | Begin capture group
| Substitute (in perl)
```

if you do not care about spacing.

Comment: the fact that you are using `(.*)` means you will capture the spaces as well and your _"if you do not care about spacing"_ can be interpreted as if meaning you are getting rid of them

Comment: Oh sorry, I guess it might come off that way.  I, of course, meant if you actually don't care about spacing and where it is, how it's formatted at the end, etc. :)

Comment: And where is that command to be used? In vi? In sed? In awk? In Perl?

Comment: As mentioned at the bottommost (and leftmost) note, this is a perl substitute operation.  You call it using `=~` on a variable like so: `$_ =~ s/(.*)=(.*)/\2=\1/;`

Comment: @U.Windl in response to your (now rejected) edit to my post.  I did specify in the answer that this is the correct form "if you do not care about spacing."  If you DO care about spacing then I need more information, because spacing is not always just one space, sometimes, it's spacing to line up various different lines visually, which might require something of a more complicated approach.  I went with the simplest approach for ease of annotation.

Answer (score 1):

the regex would be:

```
([^=\s]+)\s*=\s*(.+)$
```

The explanation is quite simple:
* one or more characters that are not whitespace nor an equal sign
* 0 or more whitespace characters
* an equa sign
* 0 or more whitespace characters
* everything else until the end of the string

The replacement string would be

```
\2 = \1
```

Comment: And where is this regex to be used? With sed?

Comment: As most languages or implementations have their own nuances, you should take what I wrote and adapt it according to the tool's recommendation

Answer (score 0):

I often use [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) for such purposes.

Just insert your code in editor, select Find > Replace... Switch to Regular expressions.
Insert following regex into Find What:

```
(.+)\s*=\s*(.+)
```

And following replacement into Replace With:

```
\2 = \1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the type of thing that I use [sublimetext](http://www.sublimetext.com) for all the time. Particularly you would use the [multi select](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZnVBVaQpWs) feature to do this.

The learning curve for this editor forces some to have headaches although the answers are just a Google away but once you've gotten your head into doing things in sublime text that you would typically just spend countless spans of time doing repetitively it becomes an invaluable tool.

For this particular problem, I would paste those lines into the editor then select one of the equals signs them hit alt+f3 (or Selection -> Quick Find All) to get multi selection cursors on all the equal signs then grab the text after each equals, remove the equals, paste the text at the beginning of each line and add an equals sign between them.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you will do this in notepad++.
Use Regular Expression Search mode.

```
Find/Search : (.*)=(.*)
Replace: \2 = \1
```

[image]